# Access State variable from outside the widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation, statefulwidget

So I've made `PageViewer` and I wasn't able to use `Navigator` inside of it, instead what I'm trying to do is to pass diferrent widget inside using `StatefulWidget` that return functions,
I want to access said `StatefulWidget` and change variable inside of it, couldn't find a way to do it

This is the `PageView`:

```
Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              children: [
                SetPage(), // Look at the bottom need to be changeable
                ],
            ),
          ),
```

and this is the `StatefulWidget` I use to pass in the page:

```
class SetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
_SetPageState createState() => _SetPageState();
}

class _SetPageState extends State<SetPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

var _page = ChooseAccount();

return _page;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `StatefulWidget` just to contain another `Widget` (`ChooseAccount` in this case). If I understand your question correctly, you want to change the `PageView` dynamically right? In that case you can do something like this:

```dart
  // List of pages in your app
  List<Widget> pages = [
    ChooseAccount(), // The choose account page
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ), // Some other pages
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
  ];
```

You can then simply use this list of pages in the `PageView` combined with `PageController` to navigate between pages:

```dart
  // Define the controller here
  PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  // Use this method to navigate between pages (for example when changing tabs in the TabBar`
  navigateToPage(int index) {
    _controller.jumpToPage(index);
  }

// Use the controller and the pages with the PageView
PageView(
    controller: _controller,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: pages,
)
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there, what but then there is option for t user to swipe among the screens, and the pageView in my app display the login view and then I want to redirect the user to sign Up or sign In view.
Is there a way to disable swipes?

Comment: @NitaiDan you can disable swipe with `PageView(physics:new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics())`, updated my answer for that

Comment: Thanks! that did it!